# Getting empty array when querying imported documents from csv file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv, export-to-csv

I used MongoDB Compass Beta (Version 1.21.0-beta.4 (1.21.0-beta.4)) to export some documents as a .csv file and then imported the documents in another database. When I try to query anything, I get back an empty array. Where do I start looking for the cause of this?

Comment: Can you check if exported CSV has data?

Comment: Yes, the CSV has around 24000 documents and the collection in the second database that I imported it in, also has the same amount of documents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but everything seems to be working fine now. I can query and get results. I'm guessing I had an elusive typo or something...